# Flutter Upgrade Breaks iOS Build

Tags: android, ios, xcode, flutter, upgrade

After upgrading Flutter to 2.10.5 my XCode build is giving me:

```
 Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[49279]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerRestoreInfoHelper is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ee5a1eb0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x107d904f8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[49279]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareAggregateRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ee5a1f00) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x107d90548). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[49279]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ee5a1f50) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x107d90598). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[49279]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABFile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ee5a1fa0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x107d905e8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[49279]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareCopier is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ee5a1ff0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x107d90638). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[49279]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABSubfile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ee5a2040) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x107d90688). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    2022-04-23 15:39:34.297 xcodebuild[49279:543408] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-04-23 15:39:34.297 xcodebuild[49279:543408] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
            { id:34E769E3-4D7D-4B02-A473-131D6ED23F66 }

        Available destinations for the "Runner" scheme:
            { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:00008103-001578E81AF1001E }

        Ineligible destinations for the "Runner" scheme:
            { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
```

This only happens run trying to run the app on to the simulator. When deploying to a physical device it runs fine.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Here is my Flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5, on macOS 12.3.1 21E258 darwin-arm, locale en-AU)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to remove old build files and configs by running

`flutter clean`

And then reinstall all packages

`flutter pub get`

Then you should be able to build

`flutter build` ...

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem here.
It's seems it's not related to the flutter version, I've downgraded from 2.10.5 to 2.10.0 and nothing change.

Uninstall and reinstall xCode did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating a new Flutter app (with the latest Flutter version) and copying over the iOS runner.xcodeproj. You have to update this file to match the details of your app of course.